# Circle around TextView Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have 3 textViews inside a linearlayout with horizontal orientation. I wanted that when one of the textview is in GONE state, I want the other textviews to be equally distributed horizontally and when only one textview is visible and other 2 textviews are GONE I want the one textView to be centered horizontally. I have achieved this using the weight attribute for each textviews.

Now I want to have a cicular background around each of the textView. Since the TextLength for each of the text inside TextViews is different, how do I make the circles equal sized for each of the TextViews?

Also, when only one TextView is available, the TextView occupies the entire width of the layout due to weight attribute. Making a circle in such case is a big problem I am facing right now.

MY xml Layout:

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/timercount_view"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="60sp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_dark"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:text="60" />

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/timercount_view"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/reset_timer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Reset"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_dark" 
        />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/restart_timer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Restart"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_dark"
        />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/start_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_dark"
        android:text="Start" 
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The drawable for cicle is:

```
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval" >
<corners android:radius="150dp" />
<solid android:color="#ff999999" />
```

Comment: I have shared the layout and the drawable for circle

Comment: You need a circle image/drawable, then put it as background of each `TextView`

Comment: use a custom xml shape as background...that´s more efficient as a png image...

Answer (score 3):

You asked

> how do I make the circles equal sized for each of the TextViews?

Set the shape's width equal to its height:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >
    <corners android:radius="150dp" />
    <size android:width="100dp"
        android:height="100dp" />
    <solid android:color="#ff999999" />
</shape>
```

You may have to do some trial and error with `radius` and `size` until you find a solution that works for your layout.

Comment: I tried it with restart_timer and start_button as visible Textviews. The restart_timer TextView looks oval even though you have provided the size attribute. The start_button does look circular though